# Reading a string with multiple options

Tags: java, string

I have String like `",yes,,,,,,,,,,,,,"` which says option2 is selected out of 15 options.  Here, a comma `,` represents a option; if it is selected then some data will be there in place of option. I need to read this string and get the exact option selected value. In above it should be option2. How shall I do this?

I have 15 options in database from which selected data is replaced here and `,` in place none selected.

Or, looked at another way, there are 15 fields separated by commas.  One field — in the example, the second field — has a non-empty value; the others are all empty.  How can I determine the first field that is not empty?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you're asking.

Comment: Do you have a string or a jdbc resultset?

Comment: Can you provide some more context and maybe a small example? Where does that string come from? What exactly would you do with the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try String.split(",") - this will return String[]

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

public class Split {

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String [] options = args[0].split(",",15);
    for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("option %d = [%s]\n", i, options[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your `String` always follows the format you specify, you can use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). For example,

```
String[] split = ",yes,,,,,,,,,,,,,".split(",");
System.out.format("The chosen data is in Option %d and is '%s'%n", split.length, split[split.length - 1]);
```

prints

```
The chosen data is in Option 2 and is 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you get a string of commas and between two commas there is some word like "Yes". Your task is to retrieve the index of that word, i.e., the number of commas (plus 1) before the word.

First of all, that encoding for an option is quite stupid, so if it lies in your responsibility, change it.

The simple solution is to count the commas before the word.

Something like this will do:

```
String s = ",yes,,,,"
for ( int i = 0 , len = s.length() ; i < len ; i++ )
    if ( s.charAt(i) != ',' )
        return i+1;
throw new Exception ("No option found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume you want to split the string on `,` like this:

```
String[] options = ",yes,,,,,,,,,,,,,".split(",");
String option2 = options[1]; //yields "yes"
```

However, why don't you use some more understandable markup, like `option2=yes` etc.?

Have a look at [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) for some library to support better options.